# Error converting JSON to kotlin data class

Tags: android

the given json is a ListOf(String , ListOf(String)). How can I represent it in Kotlin data class or java pojo class

```
{
"seats": [
          [
            "Elite",
            [
              "A07",
              "H12"
            ]
          ],
          [
            "Premium",
            [
              "C7",
              "C8"
            ]
          ]
        ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome @udhay, your json is not standard! because every this should be array or object! but in nested array "Elite" is string but second member is an array type. it's not the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Android Studio Plugin [JsonToKotlinClass](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass) which you can install via plugins. It's really convenient because you can paste in your JSON and it will spit out a Kotlin class. I use this plugin at work and in personal projects, it has become a goto plugin for my team.

Answer (score 0):

as they mentioned, the json format is not valid, you can use https://jsonlint.com to validate your json and http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to convert json to pojo.

Answer (score 0):

This is representable in Kotlin data class as:

```
data class Json4Kotlin_Base (

    val seats : List<List<String>>
)
```

Generated using https://json2kotlin.com